# how can I add reservations for a booking system in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relation

Hello im trying to make a Restaurant-Website with a simple booking-system for tables with ruby on rails (V.: 3.2.13).
I have 3 tables: Customers(name,Email), Reservations(table_id,customer_id), Tables(seats,area).

I have configured the models like the following:

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :table
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reservations
  has_many :tables, :through => :reservations
end

class Table < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reservations
  has_many :customers, :through => :reservations
end
```

I made a search with the form_tag for the choice of a table. If the customer found the right table he can click on the "book this table"-link and then he is directed 
to new_customer_path to apply his name and Email address. 
My problem is now the reservation. How can I dynamically/automatically add reservations with the chosen table and the new created customer?

Thank you in advance.

mbc0815

Comment: This might answer your question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856523/implementing-reservation-system-using-ruby-on-rails?rq=1